# Paginacion no funciona Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Buenas estoy realizando un proyecto con laravel/vuejs y Wordpress, estoy trabajando la pagina principal para mostrar el blog, me instale el paquete laravel-vue-pagination, me guio con el ejemplo y no me funciona, me dice que el metodo o la propiedad no esta definida, mas sin embargo lo coloco en mounted o created y nada.

```
VUEJS

    export default {
        props:['post'],
        data(){
            return{
                laravelData: {},
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.getResults()
        },
        methods:{
            getResults(page = 1) {
               if(page == 'undefined'){
                    page = 1
               }
                  this.$http.get('/?page=' + page)
                        .then(response => {
                            this.post = response.data;
                        });
           },
    
    
        }
    }
```

```
<div>
     <template v-for="(tarjeta, index) in $attrs.post.data">
                    <card-blog width="250px" :title="tarjeta.post_title" :paragraph="tarjeta.post_excerpt" :imagen="tarjeta.image" :link="tarjeta.url" :key="index"></card-blog>
                </template>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                 <template>
                  <pagination align="center" :data="$attrs.post" @pagination-change-page="getResults" size="small"></pagination>
                </template>
            </div>
</div>
```

```
PHP / LARAVEL CONTROLLER

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(){
        $posts = Post::published()->paginate(1);
        return view('welcome', ['post'=> $posts]);
    }
}
```

```
Route::get('/', 'BlogController@index');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el metodo y la llamada al metodo estan en el mismo componente? por otro lado (no tiene que ver con la pregunta) porque al parametro ``page`` le das un valor 1 por defecto y luego verificas si es undefined? Eso nunca va a ocurrir

Comment: buenas @AgustinG. si el metodo esta en el mismo componente, lo que pasa el codigo esta en un repositorio en el original y sin embargo no me funciona, claro esta que en vez de pasar la data normalmente lo estoy pasando como atributo o props ya que me ahorra mucho tiempo que traerlo por fetch para el renderizado.